# Does Freeform Pro save partially completed entries or "drafts"?

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace, freeform

I'm building an 8-page registration form or application and was hoping to use Solspace's Freeform Pro. I have some experience with it, but not in all of the capacities I'm hoping to use it for on this project. I know that this plugin allows you to "Create" new users, which is one of my major requirements. The other is that the user can come back and edit their application if they need to before reaching the last page and pressing the final "submit" button. I read through the documentation and it said something about data being saved for 3 hours, which would not be enough. Is this possible to do with Freeform? If not, does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?